# Install Bioconductor packages automation

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to automate installation of Bioconductor and its different packages on my Ubuntu 16.04 from R script.
However, each installation needs interaction to say -y, yes I want to install it and -a to update all.
Is there a way to automate installation? Something similar to shell's -y or yes | yes.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")    
biocLite()
biocLite("GenomicRanges")
biocLite("BiocGenerics")
biocLite("rtracklayer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can get help for the `biocLite` function with:

```
?biocLite
```

It would show the `ask` parameter to skip all the questions.

```
biocLite(ask = FALSE)
```